# Controlling variable scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I've been able to find a few similar questions but I feel that the answers provided within do not fully expel my confusion.

I have come across this question whilst playing with jQuery, but I guess that this is more of a JS question than jQuery specific.

I feel like in the below example these variables that I wish to define would be good candidates to be global, they have a wide-ranging use outside of a few functions, but I feel that I want to limit the exposure.

```
$(function() {
    $containers = $('.container');
    $childContainer = $('#childContainer');
    //Removed extra code
    var $aButton = $('#childButton');
    //Removed extra code

    $containers.hide();

    $childContainer.show(400);

    $aButton.on('click', clickChildButton);
    //Removed extra code
};

function clickChildButton() {
    $containers.hide(400);
    $childContainer.show(400);
}
```

I will have a number of buttons showing/hiding various containers. In all cases the `$containers` variable will need to be visible to the other functions to allow it to be hidden.

Should I be using global variables (or perhaps a namespacing global object hack) or is there another way that I can limit the scope of the `$containers` variable?

I'm not too keen on using anonymous functions to handle the click events as they are going to start getting a bit more complex (and contain more than just the two lines shown in the `clickChildButton` function.

Note: In this particular example it might be better to refactor the code and create a `hideContainers` function, but I am more interested in how to control the scope of variables in general rather than this particular example.

Thanks

Comment: `I feel like in the below example these variables that I wish to define would be good candidates to be global` - you should have as few global's as possible and preferably none. If you must expose something globally, expose a namespace variable (an object) and hang all other *globals* off of this namespace. The best way to limit the scope is to wrap everything in an `IIFE` and use `var` - voila - no globals.

Comment: @Adam: Thank you for your comment, I suspected that what you said might be the case. Based on your comment here and Amadan's comment below I am going to go down the IIFE route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript (prior to ES6), all variables are function-scoped. Consequently, the only way to scope a variable is to make it local to a function.

You have two basic choices here. One is to make `clickChildButton` local to `$(function(...) {...})`, as it is the only place where it is relevant:

```
$(function() {
  var $containers, $childContainer;

  function clickChildButton() {
    $containers.hide(400);
    $childContainer.show(400);
  }
  ...
});
```

If you need the scope to actually be wider but not too wide, the other choice is to wrap everything into an IIFE:

```
(function() {
  $(function() {
    ...
  });
  function clickChildButton() {
    ....
  });
)();
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. I think I am going to go down the IIFE route. Is there anything I should be watching out for?

Comment: Not really, no. Use `"use strict"` to avoid forgetting `var`, that's more or less all. Also, keep this in mind when ES6 becomes widely usable, `let` will give more precise scoping than `var`.